# List that is copy of another (not the same pointer/id) changes with the original

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm aware that simply assigning one list to another preexisting list gives it the same address e.g.

`x = [1, 2]
y = x
y[0] = 3
print(x, y)`

gives the output

`[3, 2] [3, 2]`

and to prevent this, it has to be written as such...

`y = list(x)`, `y = x[:]`, etc.

However, this doesn't seem to work in my case...

```
for i in range(layer_rot):
            for r in range(l - 1, n_rows - l + 1):
                if r == l - 1:
                    result[r][n_col - l] = int(ref_matrix[r + 1][n_col - l])
                elif r == n_rows - l:
                    result[r][l - 1] = int(ref_matrix[r - 1][l - 1])
                else:
                    result[r][l - 1] = int(ref_matrix[r - 1][l - 1])
                    result[r][n_col - l] = int(ref_matrix[r + 1][n_col - l])

            ...

            ref_matrix = result[:] # Assume ref_matrix is initialized correctly before the first iteration of the outer loop
```

I'd like `ref_matrix` to be simply a copy of `result`, but when I change `result` in the conditional statements, I notice that `ref_matrix` changes along with it. I've checked their id's, but they're both different as expected. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a *nested* `list` of `list`s, but `ref_matrix = result[:]` only makes a *shallow* copy of the *top* level `list`, so you have a new `list` containing the same `list`s as the first.

The simplest solution here is to just switch to [a full deep copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
import copy
```

then replace:

```
ref_matrix = result[:]
```

with:

```
ref_matrix = copy.deepcopy(result)
```

No matter how deeply nested your `list`s (and how mutable their contents), this will ensure all mutable elements are fully dissociated from the original `list`.

Comment: This worked! Thanks for your help!